# Reliably timing HttpClient Get request

Tags: java, android, performance, http, get

I'm trying to port a network speed test from javascript to java running under Android.  The way to speed test works is by hitting a CGI and requesting a given amount of data, and timing how long the data takes to transfer.  This amount requested is changed dynamically to provide a relatively constant update rate.

But when I try to do this under Android, I see that the amount of time it takes for the response to come doesn't seem to be proportional to the amount of data requested.  I am doing something like this:

```
    final HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm,params);
    URI url;
    try {
        url = new URI("https://myserver.com/randomfile.php?pages=250");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
    HttpParams p = httpclient.getParams();
    int timeout = 5000;
    p.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, timeout);
    p.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
    request.setURI(url);

    try {
        long t0,t1,dt;
        int rc;
        t0 = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
        t1 = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
        dt=t1-t0;
        rc=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.d(logtag,"Get response code="+rc+",t="+dt);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return -1;
    }
```

From this, I'm guessing that maybe the call to `httpclient.execute` is returning as soon as it sees the response in the headers, but before all the data is transferred.  I'm looking for the minimum amount of work required to know when the data is completely received.  I don't care what the data is (I'm happy to just throw it away, it's just random bytes), and I don't want to waste extra time processing it if possible, to avoid skewing the reported transfer rate.

What's the minimum I need to do to accomplish this?

Also, it seems like there is some extra overhead in just setting up the call.  For instance, if I try to read 4096 bytes of 1MB I am seeing about 500ms delay either way.  I'm not sure where this extra delay is coming from; is there some way to get rid of it, because this is going to skew the results a lot more than a few milliseconds pulling data out of buffers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to simply skip over the content returned using the `skip()` function of the `InputStream` obtained by the calling `getContent()`:

```
InputStream instr;
t0 = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
rc=response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
instr=response.getEntity().getContent();
instr.skip(250*4096);
t1 = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
```

As far as the call overhead, with a larger transfer it is a smaller part of the overall time.